# JQuery keyup() not firing

Tags: jquery

I cant figure out why my function wont fire. Could someone help? I am new to Jquery so forgive me if I missed something basic.

Edit code provided

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#word").val("test 1");

     $("#text").keyup(function() {
        $("#word").val("test 2");
     });
  });
</script>
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
<br>
<p id="word"></p>
```

Edit:
I have have a lot of practice since I posted this question so I will edit this to be as clear as possible and what was done to make it work.

I was to use a test area input random string and when a string has been found inside the text area, a P tag on the page would display the text, you found the script word if the string found was the screech word. IN the end I set the Jquery function to read the whole string on a keyup function and I used Regex to screech for the secret word. If people still find this question and would want to see how I did it, I will edit in the code

Comment: #text is a textarea element and #word is a p tag

Comment: @NineBerry yes I have

Comment: I haven;t used IE

Comment: Sounded similar to that problem, if its not related, I'm happy to retract the dup vote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use .val() only setting value to input tags. For inserting value into tags like div or p you need to use .html(). Below is working for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#text").keyup(function() {
      $("#word").val("You found a secret word"); //change to .html() for div or p tags
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>

Enter something: <input type="text" id="text">

<input type="text" id="word"/>

</body>
</html>
```

check the working example here
https://jsfiddle.net/n9k4v4tc/6/